# JMeter timers not waits the time configured in sampler

Tags: groovy, timer, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I try to create a scenario that I put a user defined delay in my test.

1. In the start of the test I created JSR sampler and created a variable called 
   vertica_results_delay and put in it the value of 400000.
   Than I crated a timer and put ${vertica_results_delay}, since I want the delay will be configured in the start of the test, the problem is that Jmeter ignores my value, and not wait.
   If I used Use defined field and put vertica_results_delay = 4000 it worked, but than all the tests will get the same delay, I do not want to create hard coded delay. I want to enter all properties of the test  in the start of the test using JSR.

   String vertica_results_delay = "400000"; 
   vars.put("vertica_results_delay", vertica_results_delay);
   log.error("vertica_results_delay " + vertica_results_delay);

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check [JMeter order of execution](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

> 1. Configuration elements
> 2. Pre-Processors
> 3. Timers
> 4. Sampler

Your sampler executed **after** Timer, you need to set it before,

Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) outside Thread Group with your code and the delay value will be set before Timer is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Timer is a scoped element which is executed before each sampler so what happens in your case is that :

- JSR223 Sampler is executed after Timer

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder

To fix your issue, set your timers in a setup Thread Group, or if you only want to set it from outside of JMeter, just use function [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
 and pass values on command-line:

> -Jkey=value